# How and when OpenWrt's procd runs init scripts in etc/init.d?

Tags: init, openwrt, inittab

I'm looking at a static OpenWrt firmware.
On OpenWrt initialization, `procd` is supposed to run all the `S` prefixed scripts in `/etc/rc.d` which are links to the actual scripts in `/etc/init.d`. I wonder who triggers those scripts...

I see that on `/etc/inittab` there's this line `::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS S boot` but `/etc/init.d/rcS` file does not exist, so who actually runs the scripts on `/etc/rc.d` and when does it happen on init?

I tried searching all over their documentation but still could not figure this out...
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there's really no rcS script, but the beahviour  is emulated by procd itself which runs all the scripts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the openwrt using the program procd to run the /etc/init.d/* to init the all system.
The boot sequence of openwrt is:

```
 /init - > /sbin/init -> /etc/preinit -> /sbin/procd -> /etc/rc.d/*
```

Actually openwrt always support the rcS, but openwrt didn't use this feature.